# C#: get all files which don't have any extension

Tags: c#

I am able to get files from a directory with having certain extension (example .txt),

```
var x = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test\", "*.txt");
```

But, how to get file/s which don't have any extension (XYZ below image),

[image]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch It's the same as when filtering on Windows Search. An extremely fast google search would have answered this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var noExtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\Temp\", "*.");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\", "*.");
```